# How Or why is there a limit on any primitive data types

Tags: java, type-conversion, primitive-types

In java like, short range from -32768 to 32767, while For int, from -2147483648 to 2147483647. This simply looks like early designers created some different sized buckets to store this range values.Then they would have created a bunch of more data types of different ranges, but boiled down to only 8 types with these ranges. Any reasons?

Instead of exposing a data structure (or say two one for number Other for chars) which can store some user defined dataset could also have worked.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type

Comment: Because they are 16 or 32-bit storage types.

Comment: Is this a complaint or a question?

Comment: @martijnn2008 Of course not a complaint but trying to understand the reason for the design

Comment: Downvotes Please help me understand if you can, what may be the reason behind these limits.

Comment: If you have the int 65 it costs 4 bytes. If you have the int 214567834 it also costs 4 bytes. The larger the range the larger the memory cost; hence the trade off. If you want something bigger BigInteger is (almost) unlimited at the cost of speed and memory

Comment: There was a time, where memory was expensive and every byte counted. So if you, as a programmer, knew, that you only need the range of `short`, why should you use `int` for that? I guess, that that was the reason, in many cases a `byte` or `short` was big enough and there was no need for bigger numbers, but in some other cases they were just to small and so there is a need of a bigger type.

Answer (score 3):

`byte` is one byte, `short` is two bytes, `int` is four bytes, and `long` is eight bytes. The other data types are for storing other types of data. Those numbers you mentioned are simply the largest and smallest signed integers that can fit within one, two, four, and eight bytes respectively. (And 1, 2, 4, and 8 are all powers of two.)

Comment: The questions is why byte is one,short is two...bytes.Was it just to name a range of data size? So why the data type limited to 8 bytes (for long). It should have greater data types probably.

Comment: @LondonDreams a long can hold numbers between approximately +-10000000000000000000. They probably thought that was enought. As I say if you need more use BigInteger.